# Boundary value advection equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics, hyperbolic-equations

Given the signalling problem from the exercises of Chapter 2.1 in the Introduction to Non-Linear PDE's by Logan we have
\begin{equation}
\partial_t u - x^2 \cdot \partial_x u= 0 \\
u(0,t) = g(t)
\end{equation}
Using the method of characteristics we get
$$
\frac{\text{d} u}{\text{d} t} = 0 \text{ along } x = \frac{1}{t+\eta} = C(t, \eta)
$$
for some $\eta \in \mathbb{R}$. However I'm not sure how to proceed to get a general solution for $u$. I'd assume we have to separate the characteristics with different solutions for $x > C(t, \eta)$ and $x < C(t, \eta)$.

Comment: The characteristics are $$\frac{dt}{1} = \frac{dx}{-x^{2}} = \frac{du}{0}$$ The third ratio implies $u = C_{2} = f(C_{1})$ where the $C_{i}$ are constants. Solving the first equality implies $$x^{-1} = t + C_{1} \implies x^{-1} - t = C_{1}$$ and hence the solution is given by $$u = f(x^{-1} - t)$$ Now consider what happens when $x < 0$ and $x > 0$.

Comment: That's what I've written. I don't know how to approach $x < 0$ or $x >0$. Thank you for clarifying that it should be those two cases and not in terms of $C(t, \eta)$.